# display:none not impacting on navigation bar

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries, display

I'm trying to use media queries to change the text links in a navbar to icon font characters on smaller screens utilising `display:none` but it's not working as I'm currently using it.

I'm also using Font Awesome's icon fonts using the classes `fa fa-home` etc

```css
.firstnav {
  display: inline;
}

.secondnav {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 630px) {
  .firstnav {
    display: none;
  }
  .secondnav {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home">
    <p class="firstnav">Rob Hern</p>
    <p class="secondnav poppins">RH</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#home">
    <p class="firstnav">Home</p>
    <p class="secondnav fa fa-home"></p>
  </a>
  <a href="#portfolio">
    <p class="firstnav">Portfolio</p>
    <p class="secondnav fa fa-code"></p>
  </a>
  <a href="#contact">
    <p class="firstnav">Contact</p>
    <p class="secondnav fa fa-envelope-o"></p>
  </a>
  <a href="#about">
    <p class="firstnav">About</p>
    <p class="secondnav fa fa-user"></p>
  </a>
</nav>
```

Viewing as:
[Full size screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJEaK.png)
[With media query size screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxP1r.png)

Thank you!

Comment: the code you provides works : https://jsfiddle.net/3o62mtdg/

Comment: Resize your browser. it works. :)

Comment: @VincentG Font awesome icons were showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more condition

```
.secondnav.fa{ display:none}
@media only screen and (max-width: 630px) {
.secondnav.fa {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

Because `font-awesome` icons are **display:inline-block** **by default** so you have to **overwrite** them as you are using them directly with your `p tags .secondnav class.`

> Below is a working snippet .

```css
.firstnav {
  display: inline;
}

.secondnav {
  display: none;
}

.secondnav.fa {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 630px) {
  .firstnav {
    display: none;
  }
  .secondnav {
    display: inline;
  }
  .secondnav.fa {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home">
    <p class="firstnav">Rob Hern</p>
    <p class="secondnav poppins">RH</p>
  </a>
  <a href="#home">
    <p class="firstnav">Home</p>
    <p class="secondnav fa fa-home"></p>
  </a>
  <a href="#portfolio">
    <p class="firstnav">Portfolio</p>
    <p class="secondnav fa fa-code"></p>
  </a>
  <a href="#contact">
    <p class="firstnav">Contact</p>
    <p class="secondnav fa fa-envelope-o"></p>
  </a>
  <a href="#about">
    <p class="firstnav">About</p>
    <p class="secondnav fa fa-user"></p>
  </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: This worked for me perfectly, thank for the explanation Sahil!

Comment: You are welcome :) Kindly accept the answer and upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use inline-block?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. You can see it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/buoLye6p/). Play with the vertical handler. And you'll see it works.

```
Note : Have you tried clearing your browser's cache?
```

Comment: No its not @Ruzgar try including the font-awesome library .. Then you will understand the question.

Comment: @Sahil Dhir
I already did, If you look at the left panel, you can see it as an external resource. If i hadn't, the icons wouldn't show at all. 
But if adding one more condition does the trick. That is ok.